# What is the meaning of "double-SHA256 hash of every block" in Ethereum whitepaper?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, sha256, bitcoin, double-hashing

I was reading ethereum whitepaper but I don't know what is the meaning of "double-SHA256 hash of every block".[image: Ethereum Whitepaper]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong then it should be something like

```
var result = SHA-256(SHA256(0xc63dce6747e1640))
```

Comment: Yes it is something like that, I read the bitcoin docs and understood how double hashing works. Thanks tho